# How to use the camera of an iPad connected to a Mac as a video camera?

Tags: ipad, camera

Is there a way to use the back camera of an iPad Mini as a video camera, so that I can use it from Screenflow as an input video device ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any software the directly captures the video from the camera, but like others have suggested you can capture the screen, which also works when the camera app is open, thus getting the camera video. After doing some research, it seems that you can record the screen right through Screenflow. Check out more about Screenflow screen recording [here](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/features.htm#record).

The next option, which is free, is to use the built in QuickTime application to record the screen of the iPhone. This can be done by

1. Open QuickTime
2. File -> New Movie Recording
3. Next to the record button, click the down arrow to the right
4. Select iPad Mini
5. Open the camera app and press record in QuickTime

The downside to these two options are that you won't get the native resolution from the camera, instead it is being downscaled to fit the screen size. For both Screenflow and QuickTime, you must plug in your phone, but this will provide better quality screen recording than doing it over WiFi. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for. http://www.reflectorapp.com/ It can capture the iOS view in a video.

Comment: Of course I meant use the iPad camera as a camera, not the iPad screen..

Comment: Well if you turn on the camera app, whatever is in the camera app will flow your screen. Although I don't know what the refresh rate is. It's free to try. Good luck.

Comment: Tried this app but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

AirBeam is a paid app and it works really well for what  you're describing.  I've used it and can recommend.  iDevices can be a cam or a monitor and you can view over Wifi or 3G/LTE.  And of course OS X seamlessly blends in as a cam or monitor.  For example, place iPad in the location you want to monitor and Airbeam keeps the screen black and password protected, while you view from another location via macbook.  It's easy to add another iPod if you wanted to? Check it out. Airbeam is one of the better ones.

Answer (score -1):

This app works well: http://www.ipeekcam.com/

Notes:
1. You must use `www` in the url.
2. You may need to restart your router to get it to work (that's what I needed to do).
3. Free version has limited features (but works well).
4. Use `/videoView` to view the video without other info on the page.

Comment: This looks like a kind of video streaming service. I want something closer to the device. Maybe I'm going to write it myself.